# Definition of static remote methods and their method signatures in Loopback

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs

From the loopback documentation it states that:

> Both beforeRemote() and afterRemote() have the same signature; below
>   syntax uses beforeRemote but afterRemote is the same. For static
>   remote methods, including custom remote methods:
>
> ```
> modelName.beforeRemote( methodName, function(ctx, next) { ...
>    next(); 
> });
> ```

The documentation then goes on to say ...

> Static methods have URL /api/modelName/methodName, while prototype
>   methods have URL /api/mod elName/id/methodName.

Elsewhere, an example is provided

```
module.exports = function(Review) {
  Review.beforeRemote('create', function(context, user, next) {
    var req = context.req;
    req.body.date = Date.now();
    req.body.publisherId = req.accessToken.userId;
    next();
}); };
```

Based on the above documentation ... I would expect that `create` would be a static method and therefore only have two arguments (but yet in this example above, and in practice, `beforeRemote` for `create` has three arguments.

Is there a different definition or a list of a static methods available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is an error in the documentation, since PersistedModel.create is a static method.

A list of static and instance methods is in the reference docs:

https://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/v/2.27.0/#persistedmodel